# UITableView content size while using auto-layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I want to calculate Content size of my `UITableView`. I am using autolayout  with height `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Tried to get `[UITableView contentsize]` after reloading tableview, in that case height get calculated based on `estimatedRowHeight`.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Delegate -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Trying to get content size and assign it to height constrain.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Finally I am solved my problem with some tweak. I changed tableview height to max (In my case 300 is max) before reloading data on table, so tableview has space to resize  all cells.

```
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = 300;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in detail?

Comment: I want contentsize of tableview. so I can change tableview & superview frame with respect to contentsize. I am using autolayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension. so its not working exactly.

Comment: If you are using `Autolayout` you can't change frame. You need to play with `NSLayoutContraints`.

Comment: What is the containerView for the tableView? Is it scrollView?

Comment: And when exactly you need to update the contentSize? Is it when response is received?

Comment: See this if it could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787737/how-to-create-dynamic-tableview-cell-with-dynamic-tableview-height-in-ios/35788473#35788473

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I know that. I am changing height with constraints.

Comment: @BharatModi I don't want to update contentSize, after loading data on table I want contentSize of it.

Comment: Provide the code you have tried so that one can help you move ahead.

Comment: Best answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427633/uitableview-content-size-gets-wrong-while-using-estimated-height/54434719#54434719

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Finally I am solved my problem with some tweak. I changed tableview height to max (Objective-C: `CGFLOAT_MAX`, Swift: `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`) before reloading data on table, so tableview has space to resize all cells.

**Objective-C**:

```
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = CGFLOAT_MAX;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
```

**Swift**:

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableHeightConstraint.constant = contentTableView.contentSize.height
```

Posting this so it will be helpful for others.

Comment: How do you know 300 is max(or enough). I have a tableview in scrollview, and the tableview should has a height of its content. And I find that I should give tableview a initial height greater than `([self.tableView numberOfRowInSection:0] - 1) * estimatedHeight`. Also the height must be set in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, that's just working, I can't tell why.

Comment: This actually works.
Do you know why do we have to set constraint.constant to max first? Without it this doesn't work.

Comment: it is enough to just set frame height of table view to Big_Enough_Value, then remove row and after remove row set frame height back and set tableView contentOffset to initial value

Comment: This *does* work, but since I need to animate the changes in the height constraint - it looks disgusting. It pops to really tall, and then animates it shrinking to the correct size. Though if I remove this first line, it animates nicely but into the incorrect size.. Guess I'll have to find a better solution.

Comment: I found that (when using autolayouts, and not setting a height constraint), I didnt need to add the first line

Comment: Magic, Its Worked. Thank you for saving my Time.

Comment: Setting the height to a high amount does work but if too high the view render time increases significantly. I found setting the estimatedRowHeight worked instead.

Comment: This will cause lag on my table view, but this is the only answer that works for me :( I still looking for the best practice.

Comment: Using `CGFLOAT_MAX` gives me warning `This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.`, maybe it's better to use a smaller value

Answer (score 21):

Finally, I understood you problem and here is the solution of it.

I hope you have already done this.

1. First take put some fix height of `UITableView`.
2. Then take the constraint `IBOutlet` of `UITableView` Height.
3. Then under `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method you can get the original `UITableView` height after populating the data.

Update the below code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

   constTableViewHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

> Update:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Please check this.

Comment: I did same. Not working. tableView.contentSize get calculated based on estimatedRowHeight. I need height after resizing all cells.

Comment: Thanks for help. Edited question with solution I found.

Answer (score 18):

By setting the `estimatedRowHeight` to **zero** during table view initialisation and by adding the following code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked for me!

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
 fixed it for me, thanks

Answer (score 15):

All the solutions above weren't working for my case.
I ended up using an observer like this:

```
self.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let obj = object as? UITableView {
        if obj == self.tableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let newSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
                self.tableView.frame.size.height = newSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

for swift just use

```
tableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after reloadData() 
and

```
tableView.contentSize.height
```

will works perfect.
[Example on medium](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab)

Answer (score 9):

Using `UICollectionView` for custom cell size is the best solution for me but if you somehow prefer `UITableView`, you can use KVO instead.

Using KVO is the best practice to solve this `contentSize` problem, you don't need to use `layoutIfNeeded` to force the `TableView` to update its layout. Using @OnkarK answer (the accepted answer) will cause lag if the max_height (`CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`) is too big and setting the height manually is not a good idea.

Using Swift KVO:

```swift
override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){
    if keyPath == "contentSize" {
        if let value = change?[.newKey]{
            let size  = value as! CGSize
            self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = size.height
        }
    }
}
```

Using Combine:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.publisher(for: \.contentSize)
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .sink { size in
         self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = size.height
      }.store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Using RxSwift:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.rx.observe(CGSize.self, "contentSize")
      .filter({$0 != nil})
      .subscribe(onNext: { size in
          self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = size!.height
      }).disposed(by: bag)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try two things,

1. Call below method just after some seconds of delay after tableView reloads completely.

   ```
   - (void)adjustHeightOfTableview
   {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     [self.tableView reloadData];

     //In my case i had to call this method after some delay, because (i think) it will allow tableView to reload completely and then calculate the height required for itself. (This might be a workaround, but it worked for me)
     [self performSelector:@selector(adjustHeightOfTableview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
     });
   }
   ```
2. When you call above method do not return estimatedHeightForRow,

   ```
   /*
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return 44;
   } 
   */

   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }
   ```

Just give it a try, it could help you get the problem.

Comment: Thanks for help. Edited question with solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I don't use tableView's height constraint - using auto layout, top and bottom constraint is set and only bottom constraint changes as it goes into/out of edit mode.

[Tzegenos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379620/8963597) is modified in this way: 
1. add `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0` in viewDidLoad() 
2. add the following:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    // 60 is row's height as set by tableView( cellRowAt )
    // places is of type [String] to be used by tableView
    tableView.contentSize.height = 60 * CGFloat(places.count)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to just set the `estimatedRowHeight` to a value larger than anything I deemed possible for the data I had to display.

For some reason this ensured that the `estimatedRowHeight` property wasn't used to determine the `contentSize`. I don't display the scroll indicator so it didn't really matter to me that the `estimatedRowHeight` was way off.

Answer (score 0):

You may as well subclass the `UITableView` and call whomever you want (i.e. it's container view) from it's `layoutSubviews()` where you definitely have a proper `contentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Block based KVO approach

```
var contentSizeObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        contentSizeObserver = myTableView.observe(\UITableView.contentSize, options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], changeHandler: { _, change in
            if let contentSize = change.newValue {
                self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = contentSize.height
            }
        })
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        contentSizeObserver = nil
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function inside your viewWillLayoutSubviews and call the second function after every reload. Then this problem will be solved.

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    dynamicHegihtChange()
}


 func dynamicHegihtChange(){
    yourTableName.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    yourTableName.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    let addtionalPadding = 10 
    let height = yourTableName.contentSize.height
    self.sevicesTableViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 
     height+addtionalPadding 
  }
```

//for reloading the table

```
func serviceTableReload(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.servicesTableView.reloadData()
        self.dynamicHegihtChange()
    }
}
```