# UITableview content size gets wrong while using estimated height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting empty space while I am using the *Table view content size*. I referred this like *https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81895*. But it did not work for me. When I call to get the table content size , it gives wrong size for example, if table view content size was 100 means then it gives me 140 or 80 like...etc. So, If anyone knows how to handle OR how to get correct table view content size ??

Comment: Give more information of the functions you used or post the code so we can help you.

Comment: I need to find table view content size because I need to increase table height based on number of rows. I used table view automatic dimension for automatically increase the cell height based cell contents.  So I used to find table content size after table view loads completely then we can adjust the table view size.

I used below code for get the table view content size,
      Print(tableview.contentSize)
but it gives wrong size. So I have researched some links then I found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81895.

Comment: In that link, you can see Apple says we need to mention estimated table height as 0 for get the correct table view content size. But it gives wrong content size again. For Example,

the table view load 5 rows and content size height was 100.0 means but it gives only 80.0. I don't know how to find the exact table view content size. Could you help on this ?

Answer (score 4):

use the below code once

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  yourTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "contentSize"){
        if let newvalue = change?[.newKey] {
            let contentHeight: CGFloat = yourTableView.contentSize.height
            print(contentHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this method it does not give the reflected size immediately